# Issue when singleton is in it's own file

Tags: typescript

So I'm using a singleton and putting it in it's own file but I have a hard time figuring out how to access it.  I've used it like this:

```
import Single from './ts/Single';

let test = Single.getInstance();
test.doesItWork();
```

The problem is that it returns undefined. Here is the Single.ts file:

```
export default class Single {
  private static instance:Single;

  private constructor(){}

  static getInstance(){
    if(!Single) Single.instance = new Single();
    return Single.instance;
  }

  doesItWork(){
    console.log('this worked');
  }
}
```

I had to add export to the singleton or it wouldn't be added to my final production build.  Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check `Single.instance`, not just `Single` (that is always defined because it's the name of the class):

```
static getInstance() {
    if (!Single.instance) Single.instance = new Single();
    return Single.instance;
}
```

Comment: Freak ya!  Thank you so much!  That's what I needed.